# Async has a wrong return type

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement a spinner in my wpf. If the data are being fetched the spinner should be shown but as soon as all data are fetched, then the spinner should be hidden. I know I have to use async and await for this to work but my code below doesn't work.

```
private async Task onGetFiles(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtIpAddress.Text.Contains("IP Address"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ip Address is invalid");
        return;
    } else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dpDate.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Date is invalid");
        return;
    }

    var date = dpDate.Text;
    var splitDate = date.Split('/');
    int month = Convert.ToInt32(splitDate[1]);
    int day = Convert.ToInt32(splitDate[0]);
    var year = splitDate[2];
    var filePath = $@"\\{txtIpAddress.Text}\i\Hardware Interfacing\{year}\{month}\{day}\PeripheralLogsDq.txt";

    using (new ImpersonateUser("username", "", "password"))
    {
        IsWaveActive = true;
        await Task.Run(() => LoadLogs(rbQueue, File.ReadAllText(filePath)));
        await Task.Run(() => LoadLogs(rbQueue, File.ReadAllText(filePath)));
        IsWaveActive = false;
    } 
}

private bool LoadLogs(RichTextBox rtb, string msg)
{
    try
    {
        FlowDocument flowDocument = new FlowDocument();
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run(msg));
        flowDocument.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
        rtb.Document = flowDocument;
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

My error is

```
Error   CS0407  'Task MainWindow.onGetFiles(object, RoutedEventArgs)' has the wrong return type MenuAnimation   C:\Users\Rodne\OneDrive\Desktop\AnimatedMenu1-master\MenuAnimation\MainWindow.xaml  188 Active
```

I get this error when I try to compile so I am not able to run it.

Comment: First of all, please don't post error messages as images, put the text into the body of the question. Also, which line has the error? What is `onGetFiles`? We need more information.

Comment: The error message states `Task MainWindow.onGetFiles(...)` but you did not serve this function. What is the context the using statement is called from?

Comment: The using is just my way of getting to a network. I don't have issues with it. my issue is when I call the await Task.Run...

Comment: What is the `MainWindow.onGetFiles` function? Can you add it to the question? Also the bit of code where you are calling `onGetFiles` / passing it to a delegate.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: I do not see any spinner in your code posted.  The only spinner I know is the OLE object from VB 4 that Microsoft Obsoleted in 2005.  Some people are still using this old object by registering using regsvr32.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, async event handlers (which `onGetFiles` appears to be) often have to be declared `async void`<sup>1</sup> rather than `async Task`.

This is unfortunate since it means there's no way to determine *when they've finished doing their job* using the usual `Task` based infrastructure.

However, if `IsWaveActive` is how your achieving the "show spinner until done" function, that should work just fine.

---

<sup>1</sup>Because the delegate type for the event handler, being sensible, is declared as `void` returning rather than having any type of return value.

Answer (score 0):

Do you `await` the async method `onGetFiles`? You'd better rename the method to `onGetFilesAsync` so you don't forget to await it!